# How to get id of a string array in string.xml if you have the array name

Tags: android, xml

I there a simple way to get the id of the string array defined in string.xml using it's string name? 
I have a string name of the string array, i need a way to reference that array. Below is the just an sample xml.

```
<string-array name="categories_array">
    <item>Clothes</item>
    <item>Electronics</item>
    <item>Gifts</item>
    <item>Food</item>
</string-array>
<string-array name="clothes">
    <item>Clothes</item>
    <item>Electronics</item>
    <item>Gifts</item>
    <item>Food</item>
    <item>Books</item>
    <item>Music</item>
    <item>Bags</item>
</string-array>
<string-array name="electronics">
    <item>Clothes</item>
    <item>Electronics</item>
    <item>Gifts</item>
    <item>Food</item>
    <item>Books</item>
    <item>Music</item>
    <item>Bags</item>
</string-array>
<string-array name="gifts">
    <item>Clothes</item>
    <item>Electronics</item>
    <item>Gifts</item>
    <item>Food</item>
    <item>Books</item>
    <item>Music</item>
    <item>Bags</item>
</string-array>
<string-array name="food">
    <item>Clothes</item>
    <item>Electronics</item>
    <item>Gifts</item>
    <item>Food</item>
    <item>Books</item>
    <item>Music</item>
    <item>Bags</item>
</string-array>
```

Now if  i have the array name "clothes" , how would i get it's id?

Comment: can you describe better with an example?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use this:

```java
int resId = getResources().getIdentifier("nameOfStringResource", "array", getPackageName());
```

For instance:

```java
int resId = getResources().getIdentifier("categories_array", "array", getPackageName());
```

See [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources#getIdentifier(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)).

Answer (score 2):

This can be done using reflection:

```java
String name = "your_array";
final Field field = R.array.getField(name);
int id = field.getInt(null);
String[] strings = getResources().getStringArray(id);
```

Or using `Resources.getIdentifier()`:

```java
String name = "your_array";
int id = getResources().getIdentifier(name, "array", getPackageName());
String[] strings = getResources().getStringArray(id);
```

Answer (score 0):

try `R.array.yourarray`
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```java
getResources().getString(R.string.your_string)
```

to get `String` and

```java
getResources().getStringArray(R.array.your_string)
```

to get `String array`.

Answer (score 0):

```java
String[] some_array = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.categories_array);
```